# Converting one hash to another hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Convert the following hash to another hash.

```
{["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-15", "456", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-09", "789", "user1"]=>5}
```

Convert the above hash to

```
{["2013-08-15", "user1"]=>2, ["2013-08-09", "user1"]=>1}
```

As you can see the first and second key, value pairs in the hash have same date, 
different account, and same user, in this case i need to count the total number 
of user posts as two `{["2013-08-15", "user1"]=>2}`

in the last key, value pair, the count should be one because the user posted to 
only one account ("789") even though there are 5 posts `{["2013-08-09", "user1"]=>1}`.

Comment: @mbratch Sure you can. IIRC any object can be be used as a hash key if it responds to `hash` and `eql?`.

Comment: @mbratch Sure you can. `{[1] => 'foo'}[[1]]` returns `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h = {["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-15", "456", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-09", "789","user1"]=>5} 
Hash[h.group_by{|k,v| k[0]}.map{|_,v| [v.flatten.values_at(0,2),v.size]}]
# => {["2013-08-15", "user1"]=>2, ["2013-08-09", "user1"]=>1}
```

Or,

```
h = {["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-15", "456", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-09", "789","user1"]=>5} 
h.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|((d,_,u),_),hsh| hsh[[d,u]] +=1 }
# => {["2013-08-15", "user1"]=>2, ["2013-08-09", "user1"]=>1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Facets](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets)' [Enumerable#frequency](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#frequency-instance_method) you can write this clean and modular one-liner:

```
require 'facets'
hash1 = {["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"] => 1, ...}
hash2 = hash1.keys.map { |date, code, user| [date, user] }.frequency
#=> {["2013-08-15", "user1"] => 2, ["2013-08-09", "user1"] => 1}
```

Note that unpacking the values of the array makes easier to see what's going on. Also, note that you don't need to depend on Facets, just add `Enumerable#frequency` to your extensions library, it's a very common abstraction.

Comment: I got this error      hash1.keys.map { |date, code, user| [date, user] }.frequency
NoMethodError: undefined method `frequency' for #<Array:0x007fdc2e813208>

Comment: well, of course, you need to install facets: `gem install facets`.

Answer (score 2):

Not super elegant but works.  Also, using arrays as hash keys is kinda weird.

```
h = {["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-15", "456", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-09", "789", "user1"]=>5}
h.inject(Hash.new(0)){|a,((date,post,user),v)| a[[date,user]] +=1; a } # => {["2013-08-15", "user1"]=>2, ["2013-08-09", "user1"]=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  hash1 = {["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-15", "456", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-09", "789", "user1"]=>5} 

  hash2 = Hash.new
  hash1.each do |x,y|
      hash2[ [x[0],x[2]] ] = hash2[ [x[0],x[2]] ].to_i + 1
  end
  puts hash2
```

Note that you need to use the .to_i method for first-time initialization, else we'd be adding with **nil**, but this makes it 0.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
h = {["2013-08-15", "123", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-15", "456", "user1"]=>1, ["2013-08-09", "789", "user1"]=>5}

Hash[h.group_by { |(u, _, d), _| [u, d] }.map { |u, d| [u, d.size] }]
#=> {["2013-08-15", "user1"]=>2, ["2013-08-09", "user1"]=>1}
```

Comment: +1. Note: as much as I like FP, where the use of `_` to mean "whatever" is a common idiom, I prefer to give names to unused variables, it's more clear. In Ruby at least it looks weird.